# How do I redirect a category page to account page ?

Tags: category, redirect

I want to include the account page in the main menu. So I created a category page. My first try was that I put to the `URL Key` input the value `customer/account`, but Magento saved the value as `customer-account`. After that I tried to do it from `URL Rewrite Management`, it worked until the first **reindexing**. I do not want to do it from `.htaccess`.

Is there another way to do a redirect ? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit:

In order to full fill your requirement, need  to use **Event/Observer**

Create a custom module and  using `catalog_controller_category_init_after` event for redirect to account page

**update:**

---

On this **event** fire **an observer** which redirect to **customer/account page on basic of your condition** using magento FrontController redirction action *`Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/index'));`*

*Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();*

**Observer code:**

> ```
> <?php 
> class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{
>
> public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
> {
>     $action = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName());
>     $controller = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
>     $controller_action= $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
>
>        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
>
>
>   /* here check category id and redirect to specific field */
>
>   if($category->getId()):
>    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/index'));
>   exit();
>   endif;
>       return;
>   } 
>
> }
> ```

**config.xml:**

> ```
> ....
> <config>
>   <global>
>     <events>
>       <catalog_controller_category_init_after>
>         <observers>
>             <redirect_to_account>
>               <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer</class>
>               <method>redirectNotLogged</method>
>             </redirect_to_account>
>         </observers>
>       </catalog_controller_category_init_after>
>     </events>
>   </global>       
> </config>
> ```

Comment: So I should create a new module , which will have an obsever which extend that class, where I should do the redirect?  Shouldn't be easier if i create a static block, where i should create my main menu and included in the header?

Comment: You  need to create a custom module

Answer (score 0):

Usually we approach your problem from a different point of view.
We do not modify the category tree, but only the phtml that render the nav menu.
The menù template used depends from many factors (layered nav, custom themes) but usually it is based on block:
**Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation**

in the function:
**_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml**

regards